# Convert byte array received from web service into PDF in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, pdf, nsdata

I have received byte array from web service call. I am able to generate the PDF from that but its displays error "The file “abc.pdf” could not be opened. It may be damaged ".

Comment: r u saving recieved data(pdf) in document directory

Comment: Yes with this code [myData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@NisithSeth:

I'd recommend base64 encoding your bytes and to include the encoded base64 string in your xml. Then, when you are parsing the xml, you can base64 decode the string to get an NSData which you can use to create PDF. You can find multiple code snips of how to base64 encode/decode in obj-c using Google.

Answer (score 0):

hi i think you can convert Data in to PDF like bellow and then try to open it..

```
NSData *data               = yourData //some NSData
CFDataRef myPDFData        = (CFDataRef)data;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(myPDFData);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf       = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);
```

**Update**

for CGPDFDocument information refer [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL)

Comment: I have to store that PDF into documents directory at the same time .while opening from the Documents Directory I am facing this problem.

Comment: @NishithSheth , mate see this link which used to store webview data as a PDF and i think here something wrong with save data in PDF so here pdf not open bcoz data format not valid.. i just assume that dear.. see this link which store webview as a PDF http://coderchrismills.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/making-a-pdf-from-a-uiwebview/

Comment: @NishithSheth wirte pdf like this.. NSData* pdfData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[responseData bytes] length:[responseData length]];
    [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

Comment: Yes I am writing to Documents Directory with this code 
NSArray*arrayPath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath=[arrayPath objectAtIndex:0];
const char *bytearray = [content cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytearray length:content.length];
NSError *err;
BOOL ok = [myData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
if (!ok) {
            NSLog(@"Error writing file at %@\n%@",filePath,[err localizedFailureReason]);
        }

Comment: also see this tutorial may this give some idea required http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/ i hope your problem will finished soon mate..

Comment: trying to save pdf like this.. NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];        
    NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abc.pdf"];

    NSData* pdfData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[responseData bytes] length:[responseData length]];
    [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];